# Measuring "complexity"

Tags: thermodynamics, ads-cft, complex-systems

A recently popular idea in the quantum theory of black holes is that there is an isomorphism between the interior state's volume and the computational complexity of the CFT dual (in an AdS/CFT setting). See [here](https://www.quantamagazine.org/in-new-paradox-black-holes-appear-to-evade-heat-death-20230606/) for a popular intro or [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.02287.pdf) for a slightly technical one. As best I understand it, the idea is that thermalization of the CFT state dual to a BH is followed by a continuing increase in complexity beyond the randomness implied by thermal equilibrium.

Thermal equilibrium can be measured, e.g., by putting thermometers all over a system, waiting a little while, and seeing that they all read the same. Complexity appears to be a global measure that, almost by definition, cannot be measured by an ordinary physical process. (Since if it could, that would imply that the state in question was not complex.) Is this correct? Can complexity of a physical system be measured? If not, how is this an operationally meaningful concept?